# Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I am trying to get my xml response in the correct format using HttpUtility.Decode. Upon doing and loading it in Xml Document, it is throwing the following exception : ***Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 1, position 313.*** I'm not sure why because the xml declaration does appear as the first node if I'm not mistaken. Im fairly new to XML so any help will be appreciated. How do I fix this? Thanks.

**XML decode response:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><Query_With_StringResponse xmlns="http://www.syspro.com/ns/query/"><Query_With_StringResult><?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<ARListOfCustomers Language='05' Language2='EN' CssStyle='' DecFormat='1' DateFormat='01' Role='01' Version='7.0.005' OperatorPrimaryRole='   '   >
<QueryOptions>
<ReportSequence>CU</ReportSequence>
<PriceCode/>
<PriceProductmatrix>N</PriceProductmatrix>
<ExtraFields>N</ExtraFields>
<InterestExemptionStatusSelection>A</InterestExemptionStatusSelection>
<TaxExemptionSelection>A</TaxExemptionSelection>
<CustomerSelectionFilterType>A</CustomerSelectionFilterType>
<CustomerSelectionFilterValue/>
<CustomerClassSelectionFilterType>A</CustomerClassSelectionFilterType>
<CustomerClassSelectionFilterValue/>
<GeographicAreaSelectionFilterType>A</GeographicAreaSelectionFilterType>
<GeographicAreaSelectionFilterValue/>
<BranchSelectionFilterType>A</BranchSelectionFilterType>
<BranchSelectionFilterValue/>
<SalespersonSelectionFilterType>A</SalespersonSelectionFilterType>
<SalespersonSelectionFilterValue/>
<LineDiscountCodeSelectionFilterType>A</LineDiscountCodeSelectionFilterType>
<LineDiscountCodeSelectionFilterValue/>
<TermsSelectionFilterType>A</TermsSelectionFilterType>
<TermsSelectionFilterValue/>
<ProductCategorySelectionFilterType>A</ProductCategorySelectionFilterType>
<ProductCategorySelectionFilterValue/>
<InvoiceDiscountCodeSelectionFilterType>A</InvoiceDiscountCodeSelectionFilterType>
<InvoiceDiscountCodeSelectionFilterValue/>
<CurrencySelectionFilterType>A</CurrencySelectionFilterType>
<CurrencySelectionFilterValue/>
<CreditLimitSelectionFilterType>A</CreditLimitSelectionFilterType>
<CreditLimitSelectionFilterValue/>
</QueryOptions>
<Customer>
<CustomerListHeader>
<Customer>TSAR</Customer>
<CustomerName>TSAR BUSINESS SOLUTION</CustomerName>
<CustomerShortName>TSAR BUSINESS SOLUTI</CustomerShortName>
<Branch>TSAR</Branch>
<BranchDescription>HEAD OFFICE  TSAR</BranchDescription>
<Geography>031</Geography>
<GeographyDescription>DURBAN</GeographyDescription>
<Class/>
<ClassDescription>** Not on file **</ClassDescription>
<BalanceType>Op-item</BalanceType>
<Sales>IVAN</Sales>
<CreditLimit>           0</CreditLimit>
<Currency>R</Currency>
<CurrencyDescription>Rand</CurrencyDescription>
<Telephone/>
<InvoiceTermsCode>CO</InvoiceTermsCode>
<TermsCodeDescription>CASH ON DELIVERY</TermsCodeDescription>
</CustomerListHeader>
<CustomerListDetails>
<Contact/>
<TaxNo>Tax No:</TaxNo>
<SpecialInstructions/>
<SoldToAddress1/>
<SoldToAddress2/>
<SoldToAddress3/>
<SoldToAddress3Loc/>
<SoldToAddress4/>
<SoldToAddress5/>
<SoldToAddress6/>
<SoldToGpsLat>  0.000000</SoldToGpsLat>
<SoldToGpsLong>   0.000000</SoldToGpsLong>
<ShipToAddress1>STRAUSS DALY</ShipToAddress1>
<ShipToAddress2>41 RICHFONT CRICLE</ShipToAddress2>
<ShipToAddress3>DURBAN</ShipToAddress3>
<ShipToAddress3Loc/>
<ShipToAddress4>KZB</ShipToAddress4>
<ShipToAddress5>SOUTH AFRICA</ShipToAddress5>
<ShipToAddress6>4000</ShipToAddress6>
<ShipToGpsLat>  0.000000</ShipToGpsLat>
<ShipToGpsLong>   0.000000</ShipToGpsLong>
<GSTNumber/>
<LineDiscCode/>
<InvDiscCode/>
<DefaultPriceCode/>
<CompanyTaxNumber/>
<ExemptFinChg>No finance charges</ExemptFinChg>
</CustomerListDetails>
</Customer>
<ReportSummary>
<NoOfCustomersListed>    1</NoOfCustomersListed>
</ReportSummary>
</ARListOfCustomers>
 </Query_With_StringResult></Query_With_StringResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

**My code:** Code breaks on "**doc.LoadXml(decodedXml)**;"

```
 public async Task<string> CreateSoapEnvelop()
        {
            string soapString = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
            <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
                <soap:Body>
                 <Query_With_String xmlns=""http://www.syspro.com/ns/query/"">
                <UserId>" + Settings.GUID + @"</UserId>
                <BusinessObject></BusinessObject>
                <XMLIn></XMLIn>
                </Query_With_String>
                </soap:Body>
            </soap:Envelope>";
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await PostXmlRequest("http://sysprowebservices/query.asmx", soapString);
                var soapResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


                var decodedXml = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(soapResponse);

                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(decodedXml);

                XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
                nsmgr.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
                nsmgr.AddNamespace("ab", "http://www.syspro.com/ns/query/");
                nsmgr.AddNamespace("bg", " https://bixg.choicepoint.com/webservices/3.0");
                nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
                nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

                XmlNode xmlnode = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ab:Query_With_StringResponse/ab:Query_With_StringResult", nsmgr);

                string customer = xmlnode.SelectSingleNode("CustomerName").InnerText;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string msg = ex.Message;
            }
            return "";
        }

        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostXmlRequest(string baseUrl, string xmlString)
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var httpContent = new StringContent(xmlString, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
                httpContent.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://www.syspro.com/ns/query/Query_With_String");

                return await httpClient.PostAsync(baseUrl, httpContent);

            }
        }
```

**UPDATE**

```
{
                HttpResponseMessage response = await PostXmlRequest("http://196.37.159.30/sysprowebservices/query.asmx", soapString);
                var soapResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(soapResponse);


                XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
                nsmgr.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
                nsmgr.AddNamespace("ab", "http://www.syspro.com/ns/query/");
                nsmgr.AddNamespace("bg", " https://bixg.choicepoint.com/webservices/3.0");
                nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
                nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

                XmlNode xmlnode = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ab:Query_With_StringResponse/ab:Query_With_StringResult", nsmgr);
                var xmlDecoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(xmlnode.ToString());


            }
```

Update Response from XmlDecode: "System.Xml.XmlElement"

Comment: Can you post the soapResponse instead of the decodedXml ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't roll your own SOAP client unless you know very well what you're doing. Can't you use WCF instead?

But you have a SOAP call that returns ... XML. You can't just decode the entire response as if it were HTML, because then the encoding of the inner XML will be lost, resulting in an invalid XML document.

You need to read the repsonse first, then obtain the inner XML string and then decode that:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(soapResponse);

XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ab", "http://www.syspro.com/ns/query/");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("bg", " https://bixg.choicepoint.com/webservices/3.0");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

XmlNode xmlnode = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ab:Query_With_StringResponse/ab:Query_With_StringResult", nsmgr);
```

Now `xmlnode` holds the encoded XML. Decode that and do whatever you want with it:

```
var decodedXml = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(xmlnode.InnerXml);
```

Comment: I don't think you will get the outer XML loaded in anything / any way.

Comment: @Janine _"Tried this, didn't work"_ - then you did it wrong. Edit your question to show what you've tried, as explained in [ask].

Comment: @bommelding from the question: _"XML decode response"_. The inner XML will be encoded.

Comment: The code in my answer is a literal snip, only a few linebreaks added.  You think you can read that into any Xml api?

Comment: @bommelding that's because the OP **HTML-decoded the response**. The actual response will have `<Query_With_StringResult>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?&gt;`.

Comment: OK, you may be right there. HtmlDecode doesn't seem right.

Comment: Check my update on my post Please, I decoded the XmlNode but it doesn't return the actual response

Comment: @Janine utilize your debugger or read the documentation. You need `element.Value`.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks for you help! Element.Value returned null, changed it to element.InnerXml - and that decoded it. Thanks a lot